# Wordpress restrict access to rest only

Tags: json

I'm using the wordpress only as a backend to my website so I basically need:

```
an access to the admin panel (/wp-admin/)
an access to the REST API (/wp-json/)
```

How can I turn off the whole blog view functionality? Right now it is still being crawled by bots.

Comment: What do you mean by turning off? What should happen when visiting the homepage? What about feed access?

Comment: What should happen when visiting the homepage?

It should be not accessible at all.

What about feed access? 
What do you mean by "feed" access?

Comment: The RSS feed at /feed. I would rather use hooks in a plugin to make the redirect/halt theme independent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a proper solution. But finally, I've decided to modify the blog theme.

```
<?php
function Redirect($url, $permanent = false)
{
    header('Location: ' . $url, true, $permanent ? 301 : 302);

    exit();
}

Redirect('/blog/admin/wp-admin/', false);
?>
```

So the Wordpress website is not accessible at all, but I'm still able to access wp-admin and wp-json.